# XBee ZigBee API for visual studio C++/C

Tags: xbee, zigbee

I'm sending frame using XCTU (Windows side) to mbed CPU, That process I need to do it using visual studio (windows side). Any API that compatible with visual c++? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There's an Open Source, portable, ANSI C [XBee Host Library](https://github.com/tomlogic/xbee_ansic_library) that I worked on that should suit your needs.  I'm pretty sure some people have made use of it with Visual C++.

There's also the Open Source [libxbee3](https://github.com/attie/libxbee3), "A C/C++ library to aid the use of Digi XBee radios in API mode".

Comment: i have Tried Xbee Host library but I'm getting following errors Could you please give some idea to following question. thank you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088965/build-api-library-from-git-repository

Answer (score 0):

There is also a C++ API using C++11, you find it here [xbee++](https://github.com/ferec/xbeepp)
, you can try compatibility with visual C++